# Редактирование строки объекта в массиве [Discord.js | Mongodb]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord, mongoose

мне нужно редактировать строку объекта в массиве, использую mongoose и discord.js

У меня есть массив Users, в который я каждый раз при использовании команды добавляю объект:

```
Id: member.id,
Rank: rank,
Deposit: 0,
Joined: Date.now(),
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открываю запрос в базу данных:

```
guildDb.findOne({ GuildId: guild.id, GuildOwner: status.ownerId }, async (err, docs) => {
   if (err) throw err
   if (!docs) return

   docs.Users.find(x => x.id === user.id).Deposit += +500
   await docs.save().catch(error => console.log(error)
})
```

Однако оно не изменяет значение депозита и даже не выводит никакой ошибки. Подскажете?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
docs.markModified('Users')
```

Вот это решение.